# What's the fastest known algorithm for finding the diameter of a graph?

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory

Given a positively weighted graph what's the fastest algorithm for finding the diameter for that graph?

Comment: Currently the fastest deterministic algorithm for diameter in general should be [Chan-Williams](http://tmc.web.engr.illinois.edu/detapsp_soda.pdf) which runs in $n^3/2^{\Omega(\sqrt{\log n})}$ time, matching the [previous randomized algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6680) by Williams.  But there are better algorithms when the graph is special, or if you accept approximated solutions.

Comment: I guess the OP could've searched a little more to find the answer to his question, but I am still surprised this question is getting buried so much

Comment: I think there's interesting, recent literature on this question besides the fast algorithms for APSP that Hsien-Chih mentions. I.e., see https://people.csail.mit.edu/virgi/diam.pdf which gives approximation algorithms and fine-grained complexity results.

Comment: @Hsien-ChihChang張顯之, HuckBennett, these comments seem like reasonable answers to the question, would you consider posting them as answers?